# Spark SQL errors with 'REPLACE COLUMNS is only supported with v2 tables'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, aws-glue, delta-lake

I'm running Spark SQL statements via a thrift server (Spark 3.2.0, Hive 3.1.2) running on an EMR cluster (6.6.0).

I'm trying to replace/override the schema in an external table (defined in a Glue metastore through Hive) through a [REPLACE COLUMNS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html#replace-columns) statement via Spark SQL:

```
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE gateway_dev.delta_pilot10 REPLACE COLUMNS( id int, updated_at timestamp, email string )
```

The statement fails on the following exception:

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: REPLACE COLUMNS is only supported with v2 tables.
```

The statement runs successfully as HQL - the external table schema is changed in the Glue metastore. However, I need to execute the statement through Spark SQL. I think this could be a [Spark SQL / Apache Hive compatibility](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive) failure.

My question is 1) how I can upgrade Spark to support "v2" tables (from the exception message) or 2) if there's another way to overwrite the schema on an external table from Spark SQL.

Comment: What Delta Lake version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Delta Lake 2.0.0